# vtk error: extension `GL_EXT_gpu_shader4' unsupported in fragment shader

Tags: ubuntu, vtk

I have XUBUNTU 16.04 32 bits. I am a beginner with VTK libraries. I have built and istalled VTK 7.1.1 from source. I followed the instructions from https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Configure_and_Build
The installation is ok. No errors.
I download the simplest example: [CylinderRenderingProperties](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Rendering/CylinderRenderingProperties/).
Then, I compile the example. No errors. But, when I run the program

```
./CylinderRenderingProperties
```

there is an error:

```
VTK-7.1.1/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkShaderProgram.cxx, line 395 vtkShaderProgram (0x9fd1510): 0:39(12): error: extension `GL_EXT_gpu_shader4' unsupported in fragment shader
```

I don't know what is wrong. Could be related with any graphic driver? This is the information of my graphics hardware:

```
inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: Intel Mobile 4 Series Integrated Graphics Controller
       Display Server: X.Org 1.19.3 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
       Resolution: 1280x800@60.00hz, 1280x1024@60.02hz
       GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel GM45 Express x86/MMX/SSE2 GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 17.0.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I don't need to do complex rendering. The solution was to change the VTK's CMake variable VTK_RENDERING_BACKEND from openGL2 to openGL and then build VTK again.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark either my or your answer as "accepted" so that the question is resolved, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is about your graphic driver/card. As the error message states, you need your graphic driver to support the GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 extension, which in general comes with openGL 3.2 and higher. Your current driver does not support it and in fact, according to what I found on Intel's support website, your graphic card does not support it. Apart from changing your computer / GPU, I see two options:

1) use software rendering by Mesa: Mesa has a software renderer that would offload all openGL calls to be processed by the Mesa library on CPU. You would get slower rendering, but it would work. I have never used it though, so I can't help you in setting it up, you would have to do some research on how exactly to do it.

2) In case you don't plan to do any complex rendering in VTK, you might be ok with using the old rendering backend which was the default until VTK version 7. It doesn't use anything that requires openGL above 2.1, so it should work fine on your computer. To activate it, change the VTK's CMake variable `VTK_RENDERING_BACKEND` from `openGL2` to `openGL` and then build VTK anew. It's a bit slower and doesn't have some new cool features, but otherwise it's perfectly functional and will suffice for many applications.